# Windows execute command before sleep / on power button press

Tags: windows, triggers, sleep

I want my power button to send a HTTP request before going to sleep.

I already set a task to execute with trigger `System/Kernel-Power/42` but the task executes after the next wake rather than before sleep.

Also autohotkey doesn't seem to log the power button neither does a windows trigger.

Is it possible to delay windows sleep? I could not find a way to do that.

Thanks

Comment: Why was this voted down?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this doesn't appear to be a computer **programming** question. There is no code, for example.

Comment: @RaymondChen You are right, it's a windows associated question. Do you have a suggestion where it would be better to post it?

Comment: superuser.com is the usual place for these types of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's not a real answer but I came up with a solution:

If the wifi hotspot is turned on (I need it anyways) while my pc goes into sleep mode, it sends a `System/Kernel-Power/59` and turns the monitor off.

I now have a task that listens for this and executes what I want, then turns the hotspot off and then turns the pc into sleep mode.